# Planetary vorticity vector calculus

Tags: rotational-dynamics, vectors, vortex, coriolis-effect

The planetary vorticity is the vorticity due to the rotation of the planet. This should equal the Coriolis parameter. Let $\Omega$ be the angular velocity of the planet ($U_p$ the rotational velocity) and $r$ be the radius. The vorticity is then calculated as
$\nabla \times U_p = \nabla \times (\Omega \times r)$, which can be rewritten with a vector calculus identity: $\nabla \times (\Omega \times r) = \Omega(\nabla\cdot r) - r(\nabla\cdot\Omega) + (r\cdot\nabla)\Omega - (\Omega\cdot\nabla)r$

But now this should equal $2\Omega$. I'm not sure why the last three terms are zero?

[image: Vector definitions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:  $\vec{\Omega}$ is a constant vector in this context (it doesn't vary with $\vec{r}$).  So the two terms involving its derivatives vanish.

Neither of the other two terms vanish on their own; but try calculating the quantities $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{r}$ and $(\vec{A} \cdot \vec{\nabla}) \vec{r}$ (for a constant vector $\vec{A}$) and see what you get.